# FastAPI Post APIs invoked from Angular - Same code : Different Behaviour

Tags: angular, fastapi

I am new to Angular and FastApi. I have been trying a scenario where I am invoking 2 separate FastApi end points from an Angular screen.

- I put the same Python code for a POST API in 2 separate .py files. Code provided below.
- The above python services are running on localhost, Port 8000 and Port 8001
- Now I am invoking each of these post end points from my angular app(running at localhost:4200). Code provided below.

**Python Code**

```
    from fastapi import FastAPI
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    # from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
    # from starlette.middleware import Middleware
    class Item(BaseModel):
        name: str
        description: str | None= None
        price: float
        tax: float | None= None
    origins = [
        "*"
    ]
    app = FastAPI();
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins = origins,
        allow_credentials = False,
        allow_methods = ["*"],
        allow_headers = ["*"]
    )
    @app.post("/items/")
    async def root(item: Item):
        return item
```

**Angular Code**

```
onClickTest(){
        const test = new Post("John","Desc",1,2);
        console.log("Clicked...");
        this.
        httpClient.
        post('http://127.0.0.1:8001/items',test).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response)
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
        // const post = new Test("John");
        this.
        httpClient.
        post('http://127.0.0.1/8000/items',test).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response)
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error)
          }
        )
```

Now the request successfully get processed for the Fast Api service at Port 8001 while it gives an error of connection refused for the Fast Api Service at Port 8000.
Trying to understand what might be causing that. The error message does not seem to provide much info. Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely due to a misconfiguration in the Angular code, specifically in the HTTP post requests. The first request is using the correct host address http://127.0.0.1:8001/items, while the second request is using an incorrect address http://127.0.0.1/8000/items. (Note: ":" instead of "/")

The correct host address for the second request should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/items.

To resolve the error, update the second request as follows:

```
this.
httpClient.
post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/items', test).subscribe(
  (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Man, I spend hours comparing those codes and missed catching that.

Comment: don't worry, everyone at some point made a similar mistake ;)

Answer (score 1):

in one case you are calling `127.0.0.1:8001` which is correct, in the second case you are calling `127.0.0.1/8000` which is wrong. Replace `/` with `:`